# Find directories then touch with partial dir names?

Tags: bash

I have a set of directories called "CODE (GRADE)" and would like to rename them all to "CODE" creating a new empty file inside each called "GRADE.grade".

What's the easiest way in bash to do this?

My current idea:

```
find -iname "*(*)" --exec touch {}/MAGIC!.grade \;
rename 's/ \(.*$//' *(*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only space in the path is in the target directory's name, you could get away with something like this.

```
find -type d -name '* (*)' -print |
while read path grade; do
    mv "$path $grade" "$path"
    grad=${grade%\)}
    touch "$path/${grad#\(}".grade
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy on a single filename:

```
grade=${file#*(}; grade=${grade%)}
code=${file% (*)}
mv -- "$file" "$code"
>> "$code/$grade.grade"
```

So do that on each file:

```
find . -type d -name '* (*)' -exec sh -c '
    for file
    do
        code from above goes here
    done
' -- {} +
```

(Don't mind my usage of `>> file` instead of `touch file`, just saving some CPU cycles.)